# unset roles_mask column for cancancan gem in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

I want to set the `roles_mask` integer column to set the roles of a `user`.

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_and_belongs_to_many :colleges
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
    has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
    has_and_belongs_to_many :partners



    ROLES = %w[admin college department news page ostad]

    def roles=(roles)
      roles = [*roles].map { |r| r.to_sym }
      self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r)}.inject(0, :+)
    end

    def roles
      ROLES.reject do |r| 
        ((roles_mask.to_i || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
      end
    end
    scope :with_role, lambda { |role| {:conditions => "roles_mask & #{2**ROLES.index(role.to_s)} > 0 "} }

    def role_symboles
        roles.map(&:to_sym)
    end

    def has_role?(role)
      roles.include?(role)
    end
end
```

And `user_params` in my user controller:

```
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :roles, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, {:college_ids => [], :group_ids => [], :page_ids => [], :partner_ids => []})
    end
```

And here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    ....
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-2 medium-2 small-12 columns">
    <%= f.label t("admin.user.role") , class: "inline" %>
  </div>
  <div class="large-10 medium-10 small-12 columns">
    <% for role in User::ROLES %>
      <span style="width:40px">
        <%= check_box_tag "user[roles][#{role}]", role, @user.roles.include?(role), {:name => "user[roles][]"}%>
        <%= label_tag "user_roles_#{role}", role.to_s.humanize %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", nil %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And I have `roles_mask` column in my user model.

But when I create a user, and set all the columns, `roles_mask` column is still `null`.

Comment: maybe you must specify user_params such as:
`params.require(:user).permit(:name, :username, :roles_mask, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, {:college_ids => [], :group_ids => [], :page_ids => [], :partner_ids => []})`